# What are some good references/articles/posts for Eclipse -> Intellij converts?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, intellij-idea

I've been trying IntelliJ for about a month, and mostly like it, but would like any references to good sites to useful features/shortcuts/idioms from the perspective of an Eclipse user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing better than the Jetbrains forums and blogs.

Make sure you check out the productivity guide under the help.  It's invaluable for learning the shortcuts.  It'll even tell you how frequently you use them so you can keep track of how well you're leveraging them.

Answer (score 1):

You might be past this point if you've beeen using it for a month, but for others, [this official Eclipse to IntelliJ migration FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html) from JetBrains might be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, have been through it - more looking for nuggets of goodness ;) You know, not a general guide but more "did you know..." type stuff

Answer (score 1):

A friend pointed out a plugin that will prompt you for keyboard shortcuts after you perform actions - probably the single fastest brain-pusher in my IntelliJ experience